# Querying Blazegraph for large resultset

Tags: sparql, blazegraph

Does Blazegraph support iterating over a large query resultset?  For example, given a 200GB Blazegraph database, with constantly running multiple inbound updaters, would it be possible to run a complex SPARQL query that may return a few GBs of data?

Comment: You can do this using nested SPARQL queries. Or apply FILTERS (if that makes sense in your use case). Unfortunately, Blazegraph doesn't provide a "pagination" mode or "lazy loading" mode that returns batches of data at a time.